# Equivalent of php echo in C# for inline text

Tags: c#, razor

I am trying to do something rather simple, pass a collection of data via the `ViewBag`, iterate through it, and display the data into a piece of javascript. I am using the fullcalendar.js plugin and am simply trying to add birthdays into the javascript code. In PHP I would simply use `echo '';` to display the data, however I can't seem to recreate this in C#. I have tried this a few ways:

```
@foreach (var birthday in ViewBag.MonthsBirthdays)
            {
                Response.Write("{");
                    Response.Write("title:" + birthday.FullName);
                    Response.Write("start: new Date(" + birthday.BirthDate.Year + ", " + birthday.BirthDate.Month + ", " + birthday.BirthDate.Day + ")");
                Response.Write("},");
```

But this sends the data before the document is renders and displays all birthdays at the top of the page. I have tried:

```
@foreach (var birthday in ViewBag.MonthsBirthdays)
            {
                Html.Raw("{");
                    Html.Raw("title:"+birthday.FullName);
                    Html.Raw("start: new Date(" + birthday.BirthDate.Year + ", " + birthday.BirthDate.Month + ", " + birthday.BirthDate.Day + ")");
                Html.Raw("},");
            }
```

But this simply does not print anything. I have also tried using `<text></text>` which worked to a point, however it starting throwing syntax errors on the brackets. I am using razor and this is a `.cshtml` file. Any ideas?

Also, I can confirm the data is there and the iteration is in fact working.

[image: can confirm]

Comment: have you tried `@Html.Raw("{")`?

Comment: @Rhumborl yes it renders nothing

Comment: Are you sure about how many items are in the MonthsBirthdays collection?  Trying printing out just the length or count of that collection.

Comment: @paul its 208, updated question to provide that

Comment: What do you mean by "display the data into a piece of javascript"?

Comment: Try putting @ before birthday

Comment: @mreyeros http://runnable.com/UfNTSnKMU1ZgAACt/how-to-add-calendar-using-jquery-and-fullcalendar  i am insert the data into what is in the `{`'s in this demo

Comment: @barrick apologies, I have not in this example though. however `Html.Raw"{");` still renders nothing

Comment: @alexo as embarrassing as it is to say, that did it. The calendar still isn't working yet, but the data is there now and i can work with that. Would you add that as the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the direct syntax of razor
 `@("")`

Answer (score 3):

You may try using [Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.webpagebase.output(v=vs.111).aspx) writer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a more elegant way to do this. 
First create a type to hold your birthday data.

```
public class Birthday
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
}
```

In your Controller populate your collection.

```
var birthdays = GetData(); // Get IEnumerable<Birthday>

// Return camelCased JSON.
ViewBag.MonthsBirthdays = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(birthdays, new JsonSerializerSettings() { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() });
```

In your View you would have the following code.

```
<script>
    $('#myCalendar').fullCalendar({
        // some settings here

        events: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.MonthsBirthdays)
    });
</script>
```

The sample relevant output is below.

```
events: [{"title":"Beach Volleyball","start":"2014-12-04T11:00:00"},{"title":"Golf","start":"2014-12-14T15:00:00"},{"title":"Racquetball","start":"2014-12-02T20:00:00"}]
```

Comment: I'd absolutely agree, but this is slightly different, since the output isn't JSON, but rather a javascript object (the `new Date(...)` part). So the object would be a little bit different and would require some additional conversion.

Comment: Yes, I'd agree if this were taken out of context of this problem. However, the FullCalendar can take an ISO8601 string as `start` param, so using a native `Date` object is not the only option. Documentation recommends using an ISO string. (http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)